# How can people change content of a react.js made website?

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system

If I made a website for my client using react.js, how could he or she change the website content without knowing how to code? Is it possible to do something like the wordpress dashboard?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website made with any technology can be changed but it does not mean that is hacked. Your logic to show/hide data determines whether your app is safe or not, e.g. if you hide a link to a protected route to a guest user but that is accessible using route url then it is bad implementation. You should restrict user to access that page and any apis used in that page should not be accessible without a token with proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Say for e.g. you created a website in react where there are pages like homepage, about, history, contact etc

Now your client wants to update contents, images, documents etc on their own; and they might not be technical and without using react or VS code and ftp etc.

In this case you might want to look for headless CMS like:
Contentful, Strapi, Hygraph, Storyblok

Answer (score 0):

A Headless CMS would allow your client to edit sections of content which your React App can pull into the pages. This allows you to control what the client can edit and is probably the best solution where you only want the client to be able to edit specific sections of text and image content.

For Wordpress like editing of pages composed of React components, you need a CMS that supports visual editing using React components. There are currently only two products I'm aware of that support visual editing of pages using React components.

These are [Brill CMS](https://brill.software/brill_software/cms) and [React Bricks](https://reactbricks.com/react-cms).

Brill CMS is a product that I developed for building sophisticated transactional websites that require forms, tables and interaction with a server.

React Bricks is for building visual websites and would support client editing of pages, as well as by developers.

Both products feature "What you see is what you get" editing of pages  consisting of React components, just like editing of pages in Wordpress or Wix. Both Brill CMS and React Bricks allow developers to add their own custom React components.